# Pure Javascript Algorithm To Resize Text

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typography

I have an html div that is of a fixed size and an additional HTML input box that is used to input text. This text is then displayed in the div.

I want the text to always be centred and always be the largest size possible for the number of characters in the string.

I have come up with a working prototype but it doesn't work too well.  The text is not always correctly sized.

```
function bindText(readElement, writeElement, extra){   
    //the text from the input form triggered by onkeyup event
    var textStr = document.getElementById(readElement).value;

    //the div to write the text to 
    var element = document.getElementById(writeElement);

    //the major part of the function that I have just brute forced to try and work out
    if(textStr.length > 0){                        

        //check the length of the string
        if(textStr.length > 8 && textStr.length < 12){
             //set a the font size accordingly
             element.style.fontSize = 150;
        }

        //same again    
        if(textStr.length >= 12 && textStr.length < 16){
            element.style.fontSize = 120;
        }

        if(textStr.length >= 16 && textStr.length < 20){
            element.style.fontSize = 100;
        }

        if(textStr.length >= 20 && textStr.length < 25){
            element.style.fontSize = 80;
        }

        if(textStr.length >= 25 && textStr.length < 32){
            element.style.fontSize = 55;
        }

        if(textStr.length >= 32 && textStr.length < 40){
            element.style.fontSize = 50;
        }

        if(textStr.length >= 40 && textStr.length < 50){
            element.style.fontSize = 45;
        }

        if(textStr.length >= 76){
            element = textStr.splice(0, 75);
        }
       }
   }
```

Is there a more elegant solution to get more consistent results.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: cant you just use `text-align=center` in CSS to accomplish this??

Comment: for a start, you can store `textStr.length` in a variable and replace them with it so that you don't check the length every time (and also to 'DRY'). And also use `else if` or `switch-cases` so that ifs don't keep being executed even if one already evaluated to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see in your approximation of dependence between font size and length of the text:
[image]

I made interpolation for this in form:
[image]

and you can see the results of this with parameters:

[image]

[image]

Now you can replace all your `if` and `else if` by one formula for font size `h` calculation and couple `min(h, max_font_size)` and `max(min_font_size, h)` for setting of the font minimal and maximum size.

```
function bindText(readElement, writeElement, extra){   
    var textStr = document.getElementById(readElement).value;
    var element = document.getElementById(writeElement);
    var x, h;

    x = textStr.length;
    h = Math.exp(-0.1 * x + 6) + 38;
    h = Math.min(h, 120);
    h = Math.max(h, 45);

    element = textStr.splice(0, 75);// as you wish and it is not my business why %)
    element.style.fontSize = h;

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could actually build a trial-and-error algorithm that modifies the `font-size` of your text until it is the right size.
I don't have time to write it right now, so here's a pseudo-code-like thing of what I have in mind :

```
test_element = clone(element);
test_element.innerText = text;
test_element.style.left = '-9999px'; // so that it would be hidden from the user
for(var i = maxFontSize; i > minFontSize; i--)
    {
        test_element.style.fontSize = i + 'px';
        if(test_element.width <= element.width && test_element.height <= element.height)
            break;
    }
 // and the fontSize is stored in the `i` var
```

**UPDATE**
Haven't tested it, but here's the algorithm that I was thinking about :

```
function getFontSize(text, width){
    var minFontSize = 1,
        maxFontSize = 200,
        testElement = document.createElement('span'),
        fontSize = null;

    testElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    testElement.style.left = '-999999px';
    testElement.style.top = '-999999px';
    document.body.appendChild(testElement);

    testElement.innerText = text;

    for(var i = minFontSize; i <= maxFontSize; i++)
        {
            testElement.style.fontSize = i + 'px';
            if(testElement.offsetWidth > width)
                {
                    fontSize = Math.max(minFontSize, i-1);
                    break;
                }
        }

    if(fontSize == null)
        fontSize = i;

    document.removeChild(testElement);

    return fontSize + 'px';
}

function bindText(readElement, writeElement){
    //the text from the input form triggered by onkeyup event
    var textStr = document.getElementById(readElement).value;

    //the div to write the text to 
    var element = document.getElementById(writeElement);

    //the major part of the function that I have just brute forced to try and work out
    if(textStr.length > 0){
        element.style.fontSize = getFontSize(textStr, element.outerOffset);
        // aditional, you can set the text-align property to center
        // element.style.textAlign = 'center';
    }
}
```